# using a select to find info from 2 tables that have similar columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables very similar, they both partially have same column's name (and datatype), so instead of having to select tables 1 by 1, I wanted to make it so the first table's column become same like second's table column (so like if they have 4 columns with same name, instead of having 8 column after selecting, it shows only 3)

```
JOIN items i ON i.characterId=c.characterId
WHERE i.itemId=18011

SELECT c.accountId,c.characterId,c.name,b.itemId,b.maxUpgrade,b.amount FROM characters c
JOIN bankItems b ON b.accountId=c.accountId
WHERE b.itemId=18011
```

here is an example of request I do to select a same info from both tables, I need to do 2 different request and I wish I could fusion them

table 1 (characters):

```
characterId accountId name
```

table 2 (items):

```
characterId itemId maxUpgrade amount
```

table 3 (bankItems) :

```
accountId itemId maxUpgrade amount
```

And in result :

```
accountId characterId name itemId maxUpgrade amount
```

but all in 1 request, so no need to type the `WHERE c.name=` twice

Comment: Look into `union`

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: `union` probbaly doesn't work because the bankItem table has more colums in it that I don't use, and items require characterId, bankItem require accountId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a union of items and bankItems tables within a CTE and then join the characters table on the CTE for example with either the accountId or characterId:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT itemId, NULL AS characterId, accountId, maxUpgrade, amount
    FROM bankItems
    UNION
    SELECT itemId, characterId, NULL AS accountId, maxUpgrade, amount
    FROM items
)
SELECT
    c.accountId,
    c.characterId,
    c.name,
    b.itemId,
    b.maxUpgrade,
    b.amount
FROM characters c
    JOIN CTE b ON
        b.accountId = c.accountId
        OR b.characterId = c.characterId
WHERE b.itemId = 18011;
```

Considering the table structure this solution with optional fields should work.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, it was exactly what I wanted thanks